# Spark 2.2 is using old com.google.guava library version: 14 but I need to use guava version 18 and above in SBT project

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, guava

code: var queryJob: Job = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build())

error:
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;

Answer (score 1):

**Error**: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor

**For SBT solution**:

**FIX**:
    // Shading com.google.**
    // We need com.google.guava above 18 version but spark uses version 14 and in that we don't have directExecutor() method
    // as spark give preference to spark used libraries, our code was failing

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
    ShadeRule.rename("com.google.**" -> "shadeio.@1").inAll
)
```